# "wordscount" returns letters instead of words?

Tags: ruby, word-count

I have been trying to figure out why `wordscount` returns letters instead of words, but I don't know the reasons.

Example test cases:

```
count_words("A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama")
# => {'a' => 3, 'man' => 1, 'canal' => 1, 'panama' => 1, 'plan' => 1}

count_words "Doo bee doo bee doo"
# => {'doo' => 3, 'bee' => 2}
```

Here is the code:

```
class WordCount

  def count_words(string)
    changed = string.downcase.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/,"")
    words = changed.split("")
    counts = Hash.new(0)
    words.each {|x| counts [x] += 1;}
    return counts
  end

end


test = WordCount.new
a = test.count_words("A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama")
b = test.count_words "Doo bee doo bee doo"
puts a
puts b
```

Comment: `WordCount#count_words` returns a hash that map characters to integer. What's the problem?

Comment: return just: `counts.keys.size`

Comment: it supposed to return count each words instead of letters, when I run the test file, it counts letters.

Comment: @user3221217 have you need to return he `Hash` with (word -> count) pairs? if yes you already do this =)

Comment: yes, it should be turned out like                                     # => {'a' => 3, 'man' => 1, 'canal' => 1, 'panama' => 1, 'plan' => 1}

Comment: now you calculates even not workd, but letters, is that you wish?

Comment: Are these examples the desired, or the actual behavior? If it's the desired one, what's the actual one? If that's the actual one, how do they differ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count actual *words* (e.g. '--' is not counted as a word):

```
class WordCount
  def count_words(string)
    words = string.scan(/\w+/).group_by(&:downcase)
    Hash[*words.flat_map { |w,a| [w,a.size] }]
  end
end

test = WordCount.new
a = test.count_words "A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama"
b = test.count_words "Doo bee doo bee doo"
puts a # => {"a"=>3, "man"=>1, "plan"=>1, "canal"=>1, "panama"=>1}
puts b # => {"doo"=>3, "bee"=>2}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/,"")` removes all non-alphabet characters.
- `split("")` splits the string by each character.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your method, now it counts the words:

```
def count_words(string)
   words = string.downcase.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/,"").split( /\s+/ )
   words.reduce({}) {| h,x | h[x] ||= 0; h[x] += 1;h }
end

count_words("A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama")
# => {"a"=>3, "man"=>1, "plan"=>1, "canal"=>1, "panama"=>1}
```

**NOTE:** Don't put a space before a brace `[`.

Comment: OMG! thank you so much, it's because I didn't have /\s+/ in my split !